# How to query a table to a view and publish to a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 13 SQL databases some 2005 others 2008, on a VPN.  I'd like to take all of the data from the "Employees" table on each database and make it a view at each location.  I would then like to publish these views to 1 database on another server, all in one table marking where each came from within the origninal databases.  For example the database where all the information goes to would look like this:

```
User          Name       Location
bik          Bob K          1
JS           John S         2
```

Etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ever heard of Pentaho Data Integration - The tool kettle is what you could use

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the data on the final server to be viewable, but not modifiable, and to reflect changes made to the source databases?

This would probably not perform all that well, but one do-it-yourself-way to do it would be the following (disclaimer:  I haven't tried doing this myself):

1. Set up all the source servers as linked servers on the final server.
2. Create a view in this form:

   ```
   SELECT  *, 1 as Location
   FROM    [Linked Server 1].Database1.dbo.Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  *, 2 as Location
   FROM    [Linked Server 2].Database2.dbo.Table2
   ... etc ....
   ```

You might want to read [this documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188721%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) on distributed queries, if you haven't already.

I believe it's also possible to use SSIS as the source of a distributed query, but a quick scan through the documentation didn't find anything about it.  I mention that because SSIS would make pulling and transforming data from disaparate data sources very easy, and if you could use the final recordset as a data source, you could use an SSIS package as the backend to your view.  However, again, performance would probably require considerable tuning.

Answer (score 0):

If the queries don't have to be real time you could look into using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to pull in the data to a local DB.  you could schedule the job to run hourly/daily/weekly..